# Is there a way to increase the recent files limit?

Tags: notepad++

Searching for answer I found [this old link](https://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/discussion/331754/thread/307ff17d/):

To quote:

> Is there a way to increase the recent files limit? My list shows 12
>   files. I work with large projects with hundreds of files, and the tab
>   bar rapidly becomes very unwieldy, so I try to only keep open the
>   files that I'm using for the immediate task. I cycle through dozens of
>   files in a short period of time, and I usually end up needing a file I
>   closed more than 12 files ago. Is there some way I can increase the
>   current limit of 12 to more like 20 or 30?

Looks like repo is moved to [GitHub: notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus).

At the moment I can see 15 recent files. I am using:

> Notepad++ v6.7.4 Je suis Charlie edition
>
> Included plugins:
>
> 1. DSpellCheck v1.2.12
> 2. NppFTP 0.24.1
> 3. NppExport v0.2.8
> 4. Plugin Manager 1.0.8
> 5. Converter 3.0
> 6. Mime Tool 1.9

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to Settings > Preferences > Recent Files History and change `Max. number of entries`

[image]

Comment: Maximum of 30 in my version (7.2.2). I'd happily go to 50 but maybe that would cause interface problems.

Comment: it has been always 30 AFAIK. And even at that value you already have to scroll the menu at 1920x1080

Comment: The developers *could* easily increase the limit beyond 30 with the use of a nested submenu. I'd also like to have a bigger maximum.